# Plotting partial sums of Fourier sine series

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis, compatibility, version-5

How do I plot this on Mathematica version 5.2?

$\frac{4}{\pi} \sin{x} + \frac{4}{3 \pi} \sin{3 x} + \cdots + \frac{4}{(2 N+1) \pi} \sin{(2 N+1) x}$

over $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$ for $N= 3, 6, 12, 24$.

I tried and got this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine:

```
f[x_, n_] := (4/Pi) Sum[Sin[(2 k + 1) x]/(2 k + 1), {k, 0, n}]; 
Plot[Table[f[x, n], {n, 5}], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: May be it does not work in version 5.2 of mathematica

Comment: How to get get single curve for n=5 only?

Comment: Plot[f[x, 5], {x, -Pi, Pi}] gives just the n=5 curve.

Comment: This one works for version 5.2    s[n_, x_] := 4/( π) Sum[Sin[(2 k + 1) x]/(2 k + 1), {k, 0, n}]

partialsums = Table[s[5, x], {n, 6}];
Plot[Evaluate[partialsums], {x, -π, π}]

Answer (score 1):

This is a documented behavior of `Plot` in or before *v5.2*. Just click the **More...** button in the `Plot::plnr` warning, you'll see the following explanation:

> If `Plot` is used to plot a list of functions, that list should appear explicitly as the first argument in `Plot` or should be introduced using `Evaluate` or other means.

together with a typical example:

[image]

So one solution is, as you've noticed, using `Evaluate`:

```
f[x_, n_] := (4/Pi) Sum[Sin[(2 k + 1) x]/(2 k + 1), {k, 0, n}];
Plot[Table[f[x, n], {n, 5}] // Evaluate, {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

It's not the only solution, of course. A few other solutions:

```
With[{table = Table[f[x, n], {n, 5}]}, Plot[table, {x, -Pi, Pi}]]
Plot[#, {x, -Pi, Pi}] &@Table[f[x, n], {n, 5}]
Plot @@ {Table[f[x, n], {n, 5}], {x, -Pi, Pi}}
```